# julia one-liner to write a tempfile and get its name?

Tags: julia

what is the easiest/clearest/simplest/shortest way to A) create a tempfile, B) write a string to it, and C) return the newly created file's name?

This is the best I've got so far:

```
fname,io = mktemp(); write(io, "<contents>");
# use fname...
```

Is there some clever, fancy thing I could do with `do end`? Anyone have a better suggestion? :) Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do

```
f = tempname()
write(f, "Hello")
```

which, if a "one-liner" is required, you can put on the same line

```
f = tempname(); write(f, "Hello")
```

Comment: didn't know about `tempname()`! Thanks that's nice.

Comment: @NHDaly Seems like a nice answer.  Does it deserve a check?

Comment: Yeah definitely. Thanks for the reminder, @JuliaLearner! :)

Answer (score 5):

One way is `mktemp() .|> (path->path, io->(write(io, "<contents>"); close(io))) |> first`(this only need 1 semicolon/"line" for safely close the io). I guess `do` blocks are mainly for multi-line code:

```
julia> mktemp() do path,io 
           write(io, "<contents>")
           path
       end
"/var/folders/ft/nd_bm3z52152069y78vb71280000gn/T/tmpKLWTBD"
```

Oops! the do-block way above automatically removes the temporary file upon completion. Shouldn't this just automatically `close` the io like `open`?!

Comment: The `mktemp` doc does say `and remove the temporary file upon completion` for the `mktemp(f::Function, parent=tempdir())` method (which is what the `do` form invokes). I can see the logic in that - this form is the quick and easy way to do small operations that involve temp files, while the other form is there if you need the temp file to persist through longer more complex code.